# Prove that $1$ is the supremum of $\frac{n-1}{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

My attempt:

Assume $\exists r \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $1>r\geq\frac{n-1}{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

We know $1-r>0$, by the archimedean property we have $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.:

$$n(1-r)>r+1$$
$$n-rn>r+1$$
$$n-1>rn+r$$
$$\frac{n-1}{n+1}>r$$

so any number less than $1$ can't be an upper bound, $1$ must be the supremum of the set.

Any help in verifying or improving my proof or suggesting better ways to prove this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n:=\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}=1 -\dfrac{2}{n+1}\ge 0$, $n=1,2,..;$

$1$ is an upper bound.

Let $1> r>0$. Need to show that $1-r$ is not an upper bound of $a_n$, i.e. there is a $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$1>a_n >1-r$, or $\dfrac{2}{n+1} < r$;

Archimedian property:

There is a $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.  $n >(2/r)-1$, and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

We see that if  $\frac{n-1}{n+1}>1$ and $n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$,  then we get a contradiction: $n<-1.$

Thus we have,

$$0≤\frac{n-1}{n+1}≤1$$

Now, I will show that for any $0<\varepsilon<1$ there exist $n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$, such that

$$\frac{n-1}{n+1}>1-\varepsilon$$

Algebra tells us, we have

$$n>\frac 2\varepsilon-1,\thinspace\text {where}\thinspace \thinspace n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$$

To be more precise, we can take

$$n=\left\lfloor\frac 2\varepsilon\right\rfloor+1$$

Finally we conclude that, if $n=\left\lfloor\frac 2\varepsilon\right\rfloor+1$ then:

$$1-\varepsilon<\frac{n-1}{n+1}≤1,\thinspace \forall \varepsilon \in (0,1)$$

This means,

$$\sup\left\{\frac {n-1}{n+1},\thinspace n\in\mathbb Z^{+}\right\}=1.$$

Comment: This doesn't add any comments nor verify my proof which was the goal of my post as you could tell from the tag.

Comment: @Sergio "Any help in verifying or improving my proof **or suggesting better ways to prove** this would be appreciated."